# Trouble storing form field value as jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, var

I'm having trouble storing form field values as jQuery variables. My control text is storing and recalling like a charm.. After much testing i'm still not sure where i'm missing on this. Maybe a stupid human trick that i'm failing to see?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brokenmold/f78vrs16/5/

```
<form class="ajaxform form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
    <label for="billing_org" class="sr-only">Billing Org</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="billing_org" class="form-control" value="Test Billing Co" placeholder="Billing Org"><br><br>

    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="shipping_same" id="shipwreck"> Ship Same As Billing
    </label><br><br>

    <label for="shipping_org" class="sr-only">Shipping Org</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="shipping_org" id="shipping_org" class="form-control" value="Not Checked" placeholder="Shipping Org"><br><br>

    <label for="control_test" class="sr-only">Control Test</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="control_test" id="control_test" class="form-control" value="Not Checked" placeholder="Contol Test">
</form>
```

```js
$("#shipwreck").on('click', function() {
    var billing_org = $('#billing_org').val();
    var control_test = "Control Test";

    if ($('#shipwreck').prop('checked')) {
        $("#shipping_org").val(billing_org);
        $("#control_test").val(control_test);
    } else {
        $("#shipping_org").val("Not Checked");
        $("#control_test").val("Not Checked");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brokenmold/f78vrs16/5/

Comment: Do you have a specific issue with this code? It seems like it's working fine here.

Comment: Do you mean that after checking and unchecking the value doesn't change?

Comment: The jsfiddle works fine

Comment: When checking, the billing value does not display as the shipping value as it should.

Comment: You are seeing "Test Billing Co" appear in the _Shipping Org_ field??

Comment: That's because you have no element with the `id` of `billing_org`

Comment: Wow, stupid human trick indeed.. You are so correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is flawed. There is no ID on the `billing_org` field, so your code to store that value won't work. Change your HTML for the input field to this and you should be fine:

```
<input type="text" name="billing_org" id="billing_org" class="form-control" value="Test Billing Co" placeholder="Billing Org">
```

The only change in the above from your original code is the addition of `id="billing_org"`.

It's always the simple ones that slip through!

Comment: You are so correct, I did testing on the 1 field that I missed putting an ID on.. and obviously didn't catch it. :P